# How to find most recent post for each record in related table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a one to many relationship between 'challenge' and 'entry'. I am trying to create a page that shows the most recent entry for each challenge. I don't know how to do this. So far I have something which just shows all the entries only:

```
discovers_controller.rb

 def index
    @discovers = Entry.all
  end
end
```

discovers.html.erb

```
<div id="grid-gallery" class="grid-gallery">
    <section class="grid-wrap">
        <ul class="grid">
            <li class="grid-sizer"></li><!-- for Masonry column width -->

            <% @discovers.each do |discover| %>
            <li>
                <figure>
                    <%= image_tag discover.picture.url if discover.picture? %>
                    <figcaption><p><%= discover.blob %></p></figcaption>
                </figure>
            </li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    </section>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Is there a syntax error? I tried to use it in the rails console as well and got no joy

Comment: this `discover.picture?` should be `discover.picture.present?`

Comment: Thanks Athar and test for noticing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set up relation in standard way, you should be able request entries for each challenge in the way suslov mentioned in comments: `challenge.entries`

Then you just take the most recent - `.last` the easiest way to do it, but it could not suit you if you define most recent by update_at field, for example. So, you probably would want to sort it beforehand with `.order('updated_at')` in this case (or any other relevant attribute)

In you particular case to define last entries, you can use something like that in your controller

```
@discoveries = Challenge.all.map{|c| c.entries.last}
```

Comment: But challenge.entries.last will give me the last entry for all the challenges whereas I want the last entry for each challenge

Comment: Nope, `@challenge.entries.last` give you the last among entries that is associated with `@challenge`. Try it

Comment: So putting @discovers = Challenge.entries.last in the controller gives "undefined method `entries' for .."

Comment: `Challenge.entries` - you call it on class. There is no such method for Challenge class. But there is a method for instance of class - try, for example `Challenge.first.entries`. So, you should iterate through all the challenges and set entries.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you can do:

```
@discovers = Entry.order('created_at DESC').all
```

However, I'd recommend you to use [pagination](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/pagination) instead of doing `all` in your query. As it will increase the page load time as the number of data in entries table increases.

**UPDATE**:

You ca create a scope in `Entry` model:

```
scope :last_entries, -> { order(:created_at => :desc).group(:challenge_id) }
```

then in your controller:

```
@discovers = Entry.last_entries #no need to do `all`, as it is default
```

But, I'd still suggest you to consider using pagination.

Comment: I need the last entry for each challenge rather than a sorted list of entries

Comment: @SebastianZeki : Which version of Rails are you using?